# Tradução para formação profissional

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, vocabulário

Qual seria a melhor forma de traduzir "formação profissional" para inglês? Com formação, refiro-me a cursos de pequena duração que atribui uma certificação, seja ela académica ou profissional, ao formado.

Já vi o termo traduzido para "professional/vocational training", mas, em contexto profissional, por exemplo, num CV, que termo seria mais apropriado? Existem outras alternativas?

Comment: Aqui se traduz, sim, ao português, não ao inglês. Dito isso se traduz por professional training; vocational, não. Só para electricistas ou bombeiro [Br] etc. –